# What does "'Float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" mean and how can i help it - Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was trying to follow simple instructions on how to build a game in python but for some reason it is not working and whenever i type this code in:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos=[100,100]


player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png")

while 1:
    screen.fill(0)
#Its this bit 'for' instruction that comes up with the error 
    for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
        for y in range(height/grass.get_height()+1):

            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,30))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,135))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,240))
    screen.blit(castle,(0,345))
    screen.blit(player,playerpos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
```

It says:
File "/Pygame/game.py", line 18, in 
for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

the website that i'm following is: https://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated, if not just explaining what the error means might help. 
Thanks so much

Comment: A 2-second Google search would solve this for you and save you the time of writing this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `width/grass.get_width()` returns a float rather than an int. The tutorial you're using specifically says to use Python 2.7, so you may run into other issues like this if you continue it with Python 3, but to fix this specific issue you can replace `/` with `//` to use integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(int(width/grass.get_width()+1)):
        for y in range(int(height/grass.get_height()+1)):
```

Below code working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I don't understand `Below code working` - even if it read *above*, how does this answer `What does “'Float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer” mean` or `what [am I] doing wrong`?

Comment: (Please edit your post in favour of commenting comments asking for clarification or additional information.)

Comment: You added a "cast" to int to [TryingtoProgramme's expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37122020/3789665) and found your code not giving that error message - granted. I presume you imply that *not* casting is what TryingtoProgramme is doing wrong - it isn't. Casting is not the *pythonic* way to get an integer from the division of one integer by another. Plus it doesn't even try to answer `What does “'Float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer” mean?`